# what is the commandment about beggars in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, practical-islam

I have read rules and orders about beggars in Islam but I'm still confused.

In our daily life we interact with a number of beggars, some of them are in a very miserable condition while some are totally normal (physically) and if they wanted they could work and earn their livelihood but prefer to beg.

But my main point is whenever we don't give them some money they start cursing on us, also say wrong about our future life and specially our parents. **In  this case what should we do?**

Also they gave us nepotism(wastah) of our parents, siblings, children and specially ALLAH Almighty then **what should we do**?

Because as a Muslim we have a strong feelings to help the poor and needy.

Comment: why are you making this point that some of them look "miserable condition and some are totally normal "

Comment: Like if they are not able to earn their livelihoods then they are supposed to be help out.

Comment: Normal in sense of physical fitness .

Comment: You cannot judge people on these basis, you don not know what is going on in their life. In fact you should not judge them at all. The Quran say in surah baqara to give to anyone that asks. There is also an example in the Quran where is says to give to people that look outwardly rich (due to modesty) but are actually poor

Comment: You are right but that's not my point.I m not judging them on any basis. Somewhere I read that a person(beggar) came to Masjid Nabvi and asked for help then our Beloved Prophet Hazrat Mohammad (S.A.W) said to him that do you have any thing in your home that can be sell out.Then he said yes one thing that he take from his house and Our Beloved Prophet(S.A.W) said to Sahaba's to purchase that thing in a suitable price and gave that money to that person and order him to earn his own living by using that money.Now considering that point i got confused that what we should do ?

Comment: There is only one verse in the Quran that I have come across that mentions something like this: O ye who believe! Eat not up your property among yourselves in vanities: But let there be amongst you Traffic and trade by mutual good-will: Nor kill (or destroy) yourselves: for verily Allah hath been to you Most Merciful! (4:29). But this was revealed when the prophet was giving excessive charity to the point he had nothing left of his own, which the prophet sometimes did and the people where taking everything from him at the same time.

Comment: So Allah was telling both sides here, one being unjust to himself (i.e. the prophet) and the other being unjust to the one giving charity (i.e. the beggar). In islam we believe "no bearer of burden can bear th burden of another " that is if the beggars are unjust to you that is their sin not yours, but you can at least not be unjust to yourself and not give till you have nothing. But then the question arises are you giving till you have nothing? And even here giving is encouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salaam . Bismillah.

The good news is that it's probably a little less complicated that you might think.

In [2:177](https://www.islamawakened.com/quran/2/177/default.htm), God puts it relatively plainly

> - Piety is not to turn your faces towards the east and the west,
> - but pious is one who believes
>
>   - in God and the Last Day,
>   - and the angels,
>   - and the Book,
>   - and the prophets,
> - and he gives money out of love
>
>   - to the relatives,
>   - and the orphans,
>   - and the needy,
>   - and the wayfarer,
>   - and those who ask,
>   - and to free the slaves;
> - and he carries out the communion (salaat),
> - and contributes towards purification (zakat);
> - and those who keep their pledges when they make a pledge,
> - and those who are patient in the face of adversity and hardship and when in despair (sabr).
> - These are the ones who have been truthful, and these are the righteous.

So there's probably no need to overthink it. If you have money to spare, you have options ranging from helping out a financially burdened relative in need to *freeing a slave*, which unfortunately, and apparently, still exists in 2019.

**Main point** as it relates to spending for the sake of God is *you* have the option of giving the money you've been provisioned as *you* see fit.

Withstanding verbal assaults from individuals is not recommended according to chapter 68.

> - `68:7` - Your Lord is fully aware of those who strayed off His path, and He is fully aware of those who are guided.
> - `68:8` - So do not obey those who deny.
> - `68:9` - They wish that you compromise, so they too can compromise.
> - `68:10` - And do not obey every lowly swearer.
> - `68:11` - A slanderer, a backbiter.
> - `68:12` - Forbidder of charity, a transgressor, a sinner.
> - `68:13` - Unappreciative, and greedy.

Charitable giving and giving money to purify (zakat) are good things to do. God is probably also suggesting that you give your money wisely.

Answer (score 0):

Many beggars are part of a gang and big business we should not help them whatever they say and curse.
Though it's hard to judge who's real and who's not but there are few points help to find out.

Professional beggars getup and condition you'll always find miserable.
Professional beggars always start asking and after you to beg.

Real needy people hesitant to beg, you'll not find them on road side but you have to do extra effort to find them in your locality, your relatives, in your servants, your colleagues means people around you have more rights on you and you know more better about their situation.

Don't care at all about cursing of fake beggars. If any real beggar curse you and your intention was not refrain from giving but your judgement was wrong even then don't care Allah will never give any difficulty upon you on saying of someone. This is a misconception among people that someone curse you and you'll get it's burden.

Doesn't Allah know you and your thinking and your heart and your situation better than that cursing person? If Allah has to punish you He will not wait for someone's curse.